# Using PHP to extract part of a url

Tags: php, url, extract

If you have a url like this: rapidshare.com/#!download|value1|values|value3

and you know the numbers how can you extract the value 1 and the value 3

Is there a way to extract the values between the 2nd and 3rd | and 3rd and 4th |

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to automate downloads from RapidShare, which would be against their Terms Of Use.

Comment: up vote for your assumption. However, no. But even if I did, I hate rapidshare lol.

Comment: is there a Python method for this?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = explode('|', $url);
```

And use `$array[$index];`

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about the explode function!

Answer (score 0):

```
$url =  'http://rapidshare.com/#!download|546l3|448704915|eu.heinelt.ifile_1.4.1-2_iphoneos-arm_fabius.deb|2915';
$urlparts = explode("|",$url);
```

will give you all the parts as array in $urlparts

Answer (score 0):

Al of the above are 1 way of doing this, but if your script is always extracting data after your script name. as in: **somepage.com/download.php?var1='val1'&var2='val2'** the only relevant part for you is **var1='val1'&var2='val2'**

Luckily, PHP has a superglobal that can help. `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` . This way you can get an array of values, much cleaner and not have to worry that your *explode* seperator was being used on any other part of the URL.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$values = explode("|", $url);
```